# What should I use to create a 2D game with JS (runner game)?

Tags: javascript, 2d, game-development

I'm a frontend developer and now I have a task to create a game.

Example is ⇾ http://redcarpetrampage.com/

The player should run via two buttons, only if event is "onkeyup" (or maybe "tap" on mobile).

The logic of all game is 95% like in example. Game hero should run, jump and collect something and in the end will get some score (and I should save it in database).

Popular game framework for 2D games in JS is [Phaser](https://phaser.io/), but I don't find any nice example for my type of like, like in example.

Game from example is created with [Construct](https://www.construct.net/en). I never used it before.

My experience in gameDev is - creating a few small games by tutorials without frameworks, and I have some knowledge with webGl (3d).

So I don't really know what should I do with it. Now I start a small tutorial based on Phaser, but I'm not sure is it right or not.

Hope, someone has some recommendation for me :)

Comment: if you have made game yourself, can you explain more on which part you cannot understand about Phaser?

Comment: @appleapple, I almost never develop a game via JS, so I don't know what to choose. Today the first day when I start to use Phaser, but I don't know if it good choice or not

Comment: sorry I think you mean you have develop games in JS.

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for libraries/tools are off-topic on stackoverflow

Comment: @byxor recommendations question are like "you didn't describe a problem, you just asked for a list of things". The problem is the OP never had his hands on a game framework and it is not able to map behaviors (running, jumping, collecting) to framework's features, so he is asking for help to make up for this shortcoming.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Comment: @byxor https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Regardless of the definition of "recommendation question", this post is explicitly asking to recommend a tutorial/library, and is hence off-topic according to the help center.

Comment: If off-topic it will be closed soon. For now it's not. Help center give guidelines that has to be interpreted to be applied. If the question had been "can you recommend me a library to develop js games.." you would be right but the question is "I need those features, because I'm not used to game frameworks were I can look at to find out if those frameworks meet my criteria ?". It's a collaboration matter, not a win/lose issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I'll not list game engines already mentioned, (that are very good anyway).

**CraftyJS**

As the game mechanism is very simple you can try out [Crafty](http://craftyjs.com/), it is opensource and very simple for prototyping.
It has built-in all the behaviors you are seeking for:

- [jump](http://craftyjs.com/api/Jumper.html)
- [movements with keyboard](http://craftyjs.com/api/Multiway.html)
- [collisions in order to colllect items](http://craftyjs.com/api/Collision.html)
- ...many more built-in along with a lot of useful [3rd party](http://craftyjs.com/components/) components

**PixiJS**

If you need performances and also mobile compatibility you can take a look at the stunning [PixiJS](https://www.pixijs.com/) which is more a rendering engine than a game engine, but has by far the best performance vs other engines, take a look at the performance of your device in [examples](https://pixijs.io/examples-v4/#/demos-basic/container.js) section.